# Looking for a better understanding of how this UEFI workaround for Sophos XG should be performed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, uefi

I have found a workaround to allow Sophos XG to boot without CSM but it requires this workaround.
I don't totally understand Linux but I'm working on it. I can get the /boot to mount on sda1 but I think that is on the USB not the M.2 which I believe is labeled nvme0n1. Wouldn't I want to create 2 new partitions nvme0n1p3 and p4 and mount /boot and /boot/efi in those respectively?
I'm also getting a error "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" when I try these new partitions and use "Linux LVM" as the fs type.

From https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/discussions/122369/no-bootable-device-after-successful-installation/446282

> The problem you are having is that even though the Sophos XG install
> program is UEFI bootable, Sophos XG itself is not. That's why you are
> are to install Sophos XG from a UEFI bootable USB stick, but later
> when the install successfully completes, your computer can't start
> Sophos XG from the HHD The solution? You have to manually make the
> Sophos XG in your HHD UEFI bootable.. How? Follow these simple steps..
>
> 1. Create a USB install of Ubuntu Live 18.04 (Must use only Ubuntu 18.04, since newer versions have a different (newer) GRUB version and won't work)
> 2. Boot Ubuntu 18.04 from your USB stick (DO NOT INSTALL, just select TRY Ubuntu)
> 3. Once in Ubuntu, open a terminal/command prompt window and enter the following:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin
>    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot
>    sudo mkdir /boot/efi
>    sudo mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi
>    sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi/
>    ```
> 4. Once done, take out the Ubuntu USB stick and reboot. What this does is that it installs GRUB to your Sophos XG install and makes it UEFI
>    bootable.. You can now disable CSM, since it's now UEFI bootable. So..
>    How do I know all this? I've been through this too, when I upgraded my
>    Sophos XG Firewall to v18 MR-1 You can find more info here:
>    https://community.sophos.com/products/xg-firewall/f/initial-setup/120175/uefi-boot-xg-firewall-18-0-ga-build379#pi2151=2
>    Thank Martin Gross for this solution... I'm just passing it along :)

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: You haven't clearly stated what OS/release you're using, but your pasted instructions refer to an EOSS release being Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that has only recently ended it's *standard* supported  life thus is now off-topic here.  Before the quote you mention only Linux; SE *Unix & Linux* allows questions on GNU/Linux and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, or you could try ESM/Pro support, but 18.04 isn't on-topic here (2018-April + 5 years = 2023.April for EOSS with extension till 30/31-May-2023)